# Ajax not sending request to php when url directory changes

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Now it is true that this query has not been asked and finally i giveup cos i cant find a switable answer to my query.
On my apache2 server i have enabled rewrite rules in .htaccess file in the root dir to persistently keep pointing everything but directories and files to a certain php file, this works perfectly but the problem the ajax script fails when the url changes it directory.

**here is the php script [testing...]**

```
<?php

//now if run the test using the root directory, i get clear response,
//but as i have told u, i have enabled apache2 module and added rewrite rules to .htaccess,
//meaning that no matter hat the url is, the url will keep pointing to the same file but the problem
// is that the ajax script does not fire p the request / send.
//i dont jnow what i am doing wrong...

if(isset($_GET['test_changes'])){
    echo 'the request has now reached the server';
    exit;
}

?>
```

**And here is the ajax script**

```
<script>

    //my ajax script is like this
    //the url seen below is in the root directory.
    //So briefly,how would i keep this url pointing to the same php file even if the directory changes

    $.ajax({

        url:'test.php?test_changes=123456789',
        cache:false,
        async:true,
        method:'GET',
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response)
        },
        error:function(error){
            console.log(error)
        }

    })
</script>
```

Comment: I always forget that that is really relevant, thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**please use absolute urls to accomplish the job...
see code below**

```
<?php


//it would still received the request
if(isset($_GET['test_changes'])){
    echo 'the request has now reached the server';
    exit;
}

?>






<script>
    //i had a little trouble thinking this through but i got it working after sometime
    //Now You need you ajax script url to be absolute to achieve something like that
    //by prepending a forward slash character to your URL

    $.ajax({
        url:'/test.php?test_changes=123456789',
        cache:false,
        async:true,
        method:'GET',
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response)
        },
        error:function(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
</script>
```